# negative binomial generation in SQL

Tags: sql, simulation

Is it possible to perform a random negative binomial generation using only SQL? Either directly or through some kind of workaround/table lookup?

I have all my negative binomial parameters and now I just want to simulate, say, 100 negative binomial data points.

Comment: You can use recursive CTE's for data generation. There are some examples on the web. The actual code will depend on your `DBMS`. Your question is about math, I mistaken it for data generation. Still, the CTE's may help.

Comment: With recursive CTEs SQL is Turing complete AFAIK. And your problem sounds like it is generally computable. So if that assumptions hold true, yes, you can do that in (that version of) SQL (if this is fun is another question). But questions here need more focus, like I want to compute X have tried source code Y in environment Z but it fails because of error or unexpected result U.